# Zope: cannot access REQUEST under property decorator

Tags: python, properties, request, zope

I'm trying to use the property decorator in a Class. While it works well per se, I can't use any code that has to access the `REQUEST`.

```
class SomeClass():
   #Zope magic code
   _properties=({'id':'someValue', 'type':'ustring', 'mode':'r'},)

  def get_someValue(self):
    return self.REQUEST

  @property
  def someValue(self):
    return self.REQUEST
```

Although calling `get_someValue` gets me the desired result, trying to access `someValue` raises an `AttributeError`.

What's the logic behind this behaviour? Is there a way to get around this limitation?

(I'm using Zope 2.13.16, Python 2.7.3)

Comment: Do you use a base class such as Persistence or Acquisition?

Comment: I have ObjectManager as one of the base classes (which inherites from Persistent)

Comment: as well as Acquisition.Implicit. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`property` decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) only works with *new-style* classes; that is to say, classes that inherit from `object`. Acquisition (which gives you access to the global `REQUEST` object via attribute access) on the other hand is very much 'old-skool' python and the two do not work well together, as `property` *ignores* acquisition wrappers, which are needed to acquire the `REQUEST` object.

Zope has it's own `property`-like method that pre-dates new-style classes and the `property` decorater, called [`ComputedAttribute`](http://wiki.zope.org/zope2/ComputedAttribute), which actually predates the `property` decorator and new-style classes by many years. A `ComputedAttribute`-wrapped function does know how to behave with an `Acquisition`-wrapped object, though.

You can use `ComputedAttibute` much like the `property` decorator:

```
from ComputedAttribute import ComputedAttribute

class SomeClass():   
    @ComputedAttribute
    def someProperty(self):
        return 'somevalue'
```

The `ComputedAttribute` wrapper function also can be configured with a level of wrapping, which is what we need when dealing with Acquisition wrappers. You cannot use the `ComputedAttribute` as a decorator in that case:

```
class SomeClass():   
    def someValue(self):
        return self.REQUEST
    someValue = ComputedAttribute(someValue, 1)
```

It is easy enough to define a new function to do the decorating for us though:

```
from ComputedAttribute import ComputedAttribute

def computed_attribute_decorator(level=0):
    def computed_attribute_wrapper(func):
        return ComputedAttribute(func, level)
    return computed_attribute_wrapper
```

Stick this in a utility module somewhere, after which you can then use it as a callable decorator to mark something as an Acquisition-aware property:

```
class SomeClass(): 
    @computed_attribute_decorator(level=1)
    def someValue(self):
        return self.REQUEST
```

Note that unlike `property`, `ComputedAttribute` can only be used for getters; there is no support for setters or deleters.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm using Zope for a couple of years already and never stumbled over the ComputedAttribute method.

Comment: This seems to work for me in one case (Plone/Dexterity content item), but for purposes of clarification: are there any known side-effects of using ComputedAttribute-based decorator like this on new-style classes?  What base classes must a class extend to use ComputedAttribute (for example, in a browser view participating in acquisition)?

Comment: You only can use ComputedAttribute on classes derived from`ExtensionClass` (which includes the `Acquisition.Explicit` and `Acquisition.Implicit` classes). Other than that there are no other requirements.

Comment: I know of no special considerations for new-style classes otherwise.

Comment: It is worth noting that the wrapping level one uses for ComputedAttribute might need to change for ExtensionClass 4.2.1+.  In order to use a decorator in the manner described above, I had to change level=1 to level=0.  This may be relevant especially to Plone users using ComputedAttribute in their add-ons, when upgrading to Plone 5.1+.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to route around needing acquisition and cannot explicitly set the request from calling code in the constructor of your class, use zope.globalrequest.  Otherwise, you may want to consider a browser view (which always multi-adapts some context and a request).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to zope.globalrequest. I don't have the package installed, so I'll give it a try if I ever need to get around acquisition. At the moment I'm perfectly happy with the answer provided by Martijn Pieters.
What do you mean by "considering a browser view"?