# How to decorate a function on a Dexterity based content type

Tags: python, plone, decorator, dexterity

I have a Dexterity-based content type like this one and I want to decorate a function on it to be able to access it as a property:

```py
from plone.dexterity.content import Container
from plone.directives import form

class IPhotoGallery(form.Schema):
    pass

class PhotoGallery(Container):
    implements(IPhotoGallery)

    @property
    def image(self):
        images = self.listFolderContents()
        return images[0] if len(images) > 0 else None
```

But when I access it, I'm  getting an `AttributeError`.

If I remove the decorator I can access the function. What I'm doing wrong here?

(Full code is here: https://github.com/simplesconsultoria/sc.photogallery/pull/18/files)

Comment: What's the error exactly? You have more information than we do.

Comment: As I mentined above, I get `AttributeError` if I access `obj.image`.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the function?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544129/zope-cannot-access-request-under-property-decorator

Comment: @hvelarde what is the exact error?

Comment: dear editors, the question is NOT duplicated, the answer is.